# How can I change text on a win32 window?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dialog, printdialog

Looking for hints, tips and search terms for changing the text on a win32 window from C#.

More specifically, I'm trying to change the text on the print dialog from "Print" to "OK", as I am using the dialog to create a print ticket and not do any printing.

How can I find the dialog's window handle? Once I've got it, how would I go about finding the button in the child windows of the form?  Once I've found that, how would I change the text on the button?  And how can I do all this before the dialog is shown?

There's a similar question here, but it points to a CodeProject article that is waaay more complex than needed and is taking me a bit longer to parse through than I'd like to spend on this.  TIA.

Comment: Can you refine your question a bit? I'm confused on what parts are changing to what (the acceptance button in the Print Dialog on my computer already says "OK").

Comment: +1 to Jon's comment - I get the same under Windows Vista Business

Comment: @jon (and jon... JonJon) Its always "Print" when used via System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.  Nevertheless, it matters not to the core of the question.  Button says X, I want to make it say Y, how do pls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use Spy++ to take a look at the dialog.  The class name is important and the control ID of the button.  If it is a native Windows dialog then the class name should be "#32770".  In which case you'll have a lot of use for my post in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234774/custom-button-captions-in-net-messagebox/235497#235497).  Here is [another in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259027/messagebox-bold-text/2259213#2259213).  You change the button text by P/Invoking SetWindowText() on the button handle.

---

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class SetDialogButton : IDisposable {
    private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    private int mCtlId;
    private string mText;

    public SetDialogButton(int ctlId, string txt) {
        mCtlId = ctlId;
        mText = txt;
        mTimer.Interval = 50;
        mTimer.Enabled = true;
        mTimer.Tick += (o, e) => findDialog();
    }

    private void findDialog() {
        // Enumerate windows to find the message box
        EnumThreadWndProc callback = new EnumThreadWndProc(checkWindow);
        if (!EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero)) mTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
    private bool checkWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp) {
        // Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(260);
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        if (sb.ToString() != "#32770") return true;
        // Got it, get the STATIC control that displays the text
        IntPtr hCtl = GetDlgItem(hWnd, mCtlId);
        SetWindowText(hCtl, mText);
        // Done
        return true;
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        mTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    // P/Invoke declarations
    private const int WM_SETFONT = 0x30;
    private const int WM_GETFONT = 0x31;
    private delegate bool EnumThreadWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int tid, EnumThreadWndProc callback, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder buffer, int buflen);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem(IntPtr hWnd, int item);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string txt);
}
```

Usage:

```
        using (new SetDialogButton(1, "Okay")) {
            printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: @Hans Well, DAMNIT.  I managed to leverage your code to locate the dialog, then I was able to enumerate the child windows and change all the text in those.  Except that the ONE button I needed to change did not.  See:  http://i43.tinypic.com/6xvr7m.png  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, stepped through my code and the button window SAYS its text is OK and it SAYS it changes but when the dialog appears its still "Print"...

Comment: Bummer, you seem to be doing it right from the screen shot.  I can only guess that you didn't find the right button.

Comment: I see it is the PrintDialog class.  Perhaps significant is that the Print button is the very first control, control ID 1.  You ought to use GetDlgItem() to get its handle.

Comment: I've tried `SetDlgItemText(hWnd, 1, "OMFG");` and GetDlgItem/SetWindowText but neither work.

Comment: Again, I grab the first dialog item and the text on it is OK.  Its almost as if the "Print" is placed on the button *after* I change it.

Comment: @Will: I could repro your problem.  No idea what's causing the problem, but another approach using a Timer to run the code worked.  Code added to post.

Comment: I just copied/pasted this code for exactly the same purpose (replace "Print" button with "OK" button) and it worked out of the box. Nice work!

Comment: I used this code and the legend on the PrintDialog Print button changed to Okay - which is brilliant. But is there any way to stop the Timer redraw from making the button text flicker?

Comment: I would like to add/change the button image as well. Is it possible?