# Adding custom font sizes to FontDialog

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

I'm using `FontDialog` to set up some font parameters in my app.
Unfortunately, I need some big font sizes - starting from 30 points, ending at 120 - 130 points.
But pre-defined list of font sizes ends at 72 points, larger font size has to be typed in manually, which is extremely uncomfortable.

So, the question is: can custom font sizes be somehow added to the font size list (e.g., it will look like "36 72 90 120 ...", where 90 and 120 are custom font sizes)?

P.S. 
It is not a good solution for me to use a custom control, as it is not very convenient. I'm rather satisfied with standard control except this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to not be any property to add custom values to the Font list in this control. You can rely on MinSize/MaxSize (and accept inputs via TextBox) or create your custom control.

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you, looks like it really can't be done.

Comment: It can be done, you can poke extra items in that ComboBox with CB_ADDSTRING.  You'll need to find the dialog first with EnumThreadWindows and find the ComboBox with GetDlgItem for ID=0x472.  Use the approach as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2668901/17034), alter the checkWindow method.