# Easy way to create MessageBox with "custom button"

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, message

I've a winform application, and we are trying to make it ergonomic as possible, so we respect a lot microsoft guidelines.

We have some "Deletion confirmation" to implement, and according the guidelines and what I found accross the web, the more adequate buttons would be:

`Delete` and `Cancel`

But since we use the `MessageBoxButtons` to specify which buttons we have to display, I can't see how we can do this except implementing ourself a confirmation dialog.

I don't find very logical that microsoft encourage in one side the use of "action" text on button, and the other side doesn't give us the tools to be compliant, so I think I'm missing something?

Please note that I don't need more results possibility than currently, My `Delete` option would be the same as `Ok` for me, I just want to have differents texts.

So: Is there a way to specify easily buttons we want to show different text here?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/234774/2065121

Comment: [A Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264664/how-to-change-button-text-for-yes-no-buttons-on-messagebox-show-dialog) says that there is no easy way.

Comment: Ok :( Please post this as answer so I will accept this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way other than creating your own implementation using form and show it as dialog?

We did the same some time back because of localization specialities in our project.